# Fan page and appId collision issue

Tags: comments, facebook-apps, facebook-page

I have a fan page, and I use  to show it on my website. It works great.

I decided I wanted to add `fb:comments` to my website as well, so I created an `appId`, etc. I added the SDK below the body and added the tag on the page. It causes a collision so I can't view my fan page or the comments. When I remove one I can see the other.

I am a newbie so I am confused by the usage of the fan page profileId vs. the appId I created.
How do I use both simultaneously?

(I've looked around and tried a few answers but none worked so far.)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that there's a JavaScript error on the page preventing the API code to render the page completely. Check your browser's JavaScript console to see if any errors are appearing.

Comment: thanks,i checked and came up with the following info: firstly, IE and CHROME both do not show the fan page and the comments. FF DOES show the fan page but not the comments. i used FF to get the errors and had: A.b is undefined on line 7 (lots of code can' paste here) and then: Error: uncaught exception: Error: Permission denied for <http://www.connect.facebook.com> to get property Proxy.InstallTrigger. Does this make sense to any of you? Thanks,

Comment: in Chrome i got different errors (BTW i get lots of JQuery is not defined errors on both). in Chrome i got: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'createClass2' and than 
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.tosimplybe.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=22&Itemid=36 from frame with URL http://player.vimeo.com/video/33830492?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0. Domains, protocols and ports must match....any clue here?

Comment: First, take all of the complexity of extra jQuery code out of your page and just have raw html and the code for the fb:comments on your page.  Ensure it works.  Then slowly add back in other scriptings to the page to see what breaks it.  :)

Comment: hi i tried that and it made no diffrence here are the current errors:
cssFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
static.ak.connect.facebook.com/connect.php/en_US/js/Api/CanvasUtil/Connect/XFBML:13Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'createClass2'
2Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.tosimplybe.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=22&Itemid=36 from frame with URL http://player.vimeo.com/video/33830492?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Comment: If you had barebones HTML on the page with just the plugin, either you're not pointing to the right version of the plugin or there's a server issue.  What else can it be?  Post your complete HTML page's code in your question above (or a link to the page you are testing with)

Comment: (I just checked http://www.tosimplybe.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=22&Itemid=36 and this is clearly not a bare bones HTML page with everything removed but the plugin...)

Comment: Thanks DMCS,
the javascript issues were a wild goose chase.
the problem was that FB changed their code (i guess) and instead of a fanbox they now have a like box.
once i added the like box code it worked perfectly. 
here is the link to the social plugins:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/
good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. and no it did not solve my problem.
if i remember correctly i used the new FB code and that made it work.

Comment: Didn't I recommend doing this: "pointing to the right version of the plugin". ?